# A list of Java errors and warnings

Tags: java, warnings

Where/How could I get a list of all the java and javac's error and warning messages?

Comment: Write software, and make a list as you come across them :)

Comment: Watch me coding - after 2-3 days you have the complete list ;-) (and a dictionary of german swear words for free)

Comment: @Dolph : That would take while :)
@Andreas_D: could always use a list of german swear words :P

Comment: My all-purpose German swear word: "fliegenkindscheiße!" (flying baby *poo*!"). It's a good phrase to know in any language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/compileerrormessages.html) page is I think what you need.

Comment: @Saif : From a bit of googling I just did, this seems to be the only compilation of its sort.

Comment: @Stephen : The page doesn't list the **warning** messages of javac.

Comment: guess i'll be heading for the jdk source code sooner or later :(

Comment: @Saif : Going thru Java Language Spec may help you.

Comment: @Rahul G: Thanks! I just found the book on amazon, looks great :D

Answer (score 1):

mindprod.com has a Java Glossary with runtime and compile time lists:

http://mindprod.com/jgloss/errormessages.html

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

[This list of exceptions](http://rymden.nu/exceptions.html) is much more interesting than any of the above answers.

It might not be as useful or as complete, but it's good reading nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean Java Exception?

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html

This is a list of every exception that Java will at run-time. If you are refering to syntax errors you maybe look at [learning Java](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/)

Comment: That certainly covers a part of it, but what about the warning messages?

Answer (score 0):

You could look through the source code, since it's open source.

But more importantly - I can't think of a single reason why you'd want to do this.  What's your *real* question here; what are you trying to achieve?  It's almost certain you're going about it in a suboptimal fashion...

Comment: That would be the long way around. I am developing an Arabic translation to Java and would like to translate the errors and messages too.