# What is the complexity of a circular doubly linked list using binary search?

Tags: linked-list, complexity-theory

Is it O(n log n) or O(log n)?

Comment: @Frustrated - Why did you tag this with `homework`? Saif says [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326831/a-list-of-java-errors-and-warnings/2326876#2326876) that he's developing a translation of Java to Arabic, not exactly a student-level task.

Comment: @reemrevnivek: I tagged it `homework` because it looks very much like a homework question: no background of the problem, no explanation of *why* he wants to do a binary search using a circular doubly linked list, and it *looks* like homeworks questions I had received and seen others receive.
@Saif: Sorry if it wasn't homework, but it had the appearance of it.

Comment: @Frustrated: thats alright. Actually I was curious and didn't think it through, I was already taught (not a homework though :P) that it was inefficient but I was thinking why would it be so if I used cached pointers, my bad for not thinking it through though.

Comment: You didn't mention anything about cached pointers... not completely sure what you meant by that but that *might* be worth a new question, as long as it's clear and precise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to say it's not O(log n) because binary searches don't work well on linked lists - you don't have efficient random access.

If you really tried to do binary search, it would take O(log n) steps, but in each step, you need an O(n) traversal to access the desired element. So you could say it's O(nlog(n)).

You should just do a O(n) linear search instead.

Comment: You don't have *any* random access; all access is linear. But, yes, I agree with your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Binary search requires random access, hence it's not possible on a linked list. You're stuck with an O(n) linear search.